# Android: setTheme(int style) has some delays

Tags: java, android, android-theme

This is my first post and I am not good at English, so I'd appreciate it if you do not feel bad.

Nice to meet you, always being indebted.

My android application has the main activity with some fragments, and main activity theme modifier, an external class.

I tried to change the theme of activity with theme modifier, and it works, but *setTheme(int style)* has delay about 0.3~0.5 seconds. I want to make no delay, or setTheme(int style) works first.

Here is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private MainActivityThemeModifier matm = null;
    // Actually, there are more buttons, but I'll write just these two.
    private Button btnRadio = null;
    private Button btnHome = null;
    private LinearLayout layBody = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        matm = new MainActivityThemeModifier(this);
        matm.modifyOnCreate();

        btnRadio = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRadio);
        btnHome = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnHome);
        layBody = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layBody);
    }

    // onCreateOptionMenu, onOptionItemSelected here

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case "radio":
                TemporaryVO.TARGET_FRAGMENT = "radio";
                matm.modifyOnClick();
                break;

            case R.id.btnHome:
                Log.d(TAG, "btnHome Clicked");
                TemporaryVO.TARGET_FRAGMENT = "home";
                matm.modifyOnClick();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my MainActivityThemeModifier:

```
public class MainActivityThemeModifier {
    private MainActivity activity = null;

    public MainActivityThemeModifier(MainActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    private void changeTheme(int theme) {
        activity.setTheme(theme);
        activity.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    private void setButtonTextColor(int targetButton, int[] otherButtons, int color) {
        // Set textColor of targetButton
        Button target = (Button) activity.findViewById(targetButton);
        target.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, color));

        // Set textColor of Other Buttons
        Button[] others = new Button[4];
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
            others[i] = (Button) activity.findViewById(otherButtons[i]);
            others[i].setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, R.color.textNormal40));
        }
    }

    private void setFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.layBody, fragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }

    private void refreshActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, activity.getClass());
        activity.startActivity(intent);
        activity.overridePendingTransition(0,0);
        activity.finish();
    }

    public void modifyOnCreate() {
        switch (TemporaryVO.TARGET_FRAGMENT) {
            case "radio":
                changeTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Yellow);
                // public void modifyOnClick() has refreshActivity(); here
                activity.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                setButtonTextColor(R.id.btnRadio,
                                   new int[]{R.id.btn0, R.id.btnHome, R.id.btn3, R.id.btn4},
                                   R.color.yellowDark100);
                setFragment(new RadioFragment());
                break;

            case "home":
                changeTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
                activity.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                setButtonTextColor(R.id.btnHome,
                                   new int[]{R.id.btn0, R.id.btnRadio, R.id.btn3, R.id.btn4},
                                   R.color.textNormal100);
                setFragment(new HomeFragment());
                break;
        }
    }
```

I want to operate in the following order:
1) Change(set) theme and apply
2) Change(set) button’s text color and apply
3) Show body with fragment

But it works in the following order:
2) Change(set) button’s text color and apply
3) Show body with fragment
1) Change(set) theme and apply

I tried searching for hours, but I still have no idea.
How can I operate the workflow?
Thank you for your reply.